# Rails 3: How much time does a method takes to run

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, execution-time

I want to receive information concerning how much time does a method takes to run. How can I do that in rails without using `NewRelic`?

Comment: a simple test of creating a date object in the beginning and another one in the end, and checking the difference between those date objects didn't work for you?

Comment: @bluefoot I need something more realiable

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ruby-prof](http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: Link is dead. I assume this is the correct library: [https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof](https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Ruby's Benchmark class...
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/classes/Benchmark.html